# How to search MYSQL database with a few WHEREs

Tags: php, mysql

EDIT:

Here is my table:

[user_friend] table:

- id, -user_id
- friend_id
- time

[late] table:

- id
- user_id
- reason
- check_in_time

Now, let's just say the current user's id is '1', I want to search the table user_friend for all the rows with the user_id of '1' then put all the friend_id all the rows with user_id of '1' in a var or something(Let's just say there 3 rows with the friend_id of 2,3 $ 4 respectively).

Now I want to get the id of the rows in the late table with the user_id of any of the current user's friend's id(For this case it's 2,3 & 4). Hope it helps

Comment: SQL 101: `WHERE (condition 1) AND (condition 2)`... ?

Comment: Please show us the table structure.

Comment: WHERE _ OR _ /
WHERE _ IN (_, _, _)

Comment: There's many friend id that is needed to be extracted from the user_friends table

Comment: I'd echo @EM-Creations and suggest putting up a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com)

Comment: My tables: [user_friend] table: -id, -user_id, -friend_id, -time [late] table: -id, -user_id, -reason, -check_in_time. Now, let's just say the current user's id is '1', I want to search the table user_friend for all the rows with the user_id of '1' then put all the friend_id all the rows with user_id of '1' in a var or something(Let's just say there 3 rows with the friend_id of 2,3 $ 4 respectively). Now I want to get the id of the rows in the late table with the user_id of any of the current user's friend's id(For this case it's 2,3 & 4). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

If i understand your new info correctly this will select a list of `friend_id`'s from the `user_friend` table where the current `user_id` = 1. It will then use this list of `friend_id`'s to select all those entries from `late` where those `friend_id`'s appear.

```
SELECT * FROM late WHERE user_id IN (SELECT friend_id FROM user_friend where user_id=1);
```

You could also achieve the same using table joins. But it isn't as easy to explain.

**Original Response**
Suggest a way of doing this may be to use a `WHERE IN (SUB SELECT)` but this may not be the most efficient... it going to depend on your data structure and quantity of data - but you dont provide enough information...

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM late WHERE user_id IN (SELECT * FROM user_friends WHERE id IN (1,2,3));
```

As i said there are most definatley better ways - but more information would help.

Comment: I gave everything already

Comment: Let me give you another example, like Facebook, to get the current user's friend's post you'll have to get the current user's friends' ids first the search for their post in another table with their id, does anyone know the MYSQL query for that

Comment: No you didn't... there is no description of the internals of your tables, no indication on the volumes of data. If you think you have given everything for someone to help you out here.... well....

Comment: And i have given you a suggestion based on the best information i have....

Comment: Ohh, you want my table? Here it is [user_friend] table: -id, -user_id, -friend_id, -time [late] table: -id, -user_id, -reason, -check_in_time. Now, let's just say the current user's id is '1', I want to search the table user_friend for all the rows with the user_id of '1' then put all the friend_id all the rows with user_id of '1' in a var or something(Let's just say there 3 rows with the friend_id of 2,3 $ 4 respectively). Now I want to get the id of the rows in the late table with the user_id of any of the current user's friend's id(For this case it's 2,3 & 4). Hope it helps.

Comment: Please could you update the question with the above - with some proper formatting... it is difficult to read here and benefits nobody who comes accross this open question.

Comment: Alright, I've edited my post, please help

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and give you the result soon

Comment: Thank you man, it works but when there's more than 1 data in the user_friend and late table it shows the same data(In this case, I'm showing the same late table's row id). Are there any way to choose the next friend_id every time the query is called(I'm using PHP while loop)[Please nota that the next friend_id isn't in sequence so you can't do equations to it. Example: 1st friend_id=2, 2nd friend_id=5] Help please

Comment: Not sure i understand.

Comment: Nevermind I got it, but it's gonna lag the user a bit though